# How to bring QLineEdit() & QPushButton to centre of Login window?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I am creating a LoginWindow and am using QLineEdit in order to make a place for my users to enter their details. Right now, I'm focused on creating the GUI. As shown in the picture, I am not sure why the layout looks like that, considering how I have `setAlignment` to `AlignCenter`. This also goes for QPushButton. Is there a class I am not aware to fix this formatting issue?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout
import time #For time sleep

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("MidiScribe - Login Window")
        self.setFixedSize(800,800)
        self.setStyleSheet("""background-color: crimson;
                            border-color: maroon;
                            border: 2.5px outset rgb(128, 128, 128);
                            border-radius: 3px;""")
        container = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(container)

        self.username = QLineEdit()
        self.username.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.username.setStyleSheet("""background-color: white;""")
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.username)
        self.username.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.password = QLineEdit()
        self.password.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.password.setStyleSheet("""background-color: white""")
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.password)
        self.password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.loginbutton = QPushButton("Login")
        self.loginbutton.setFixedSize(50,50)
        self.loginbutton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: lightcoral }"
                        "QPushButton:Hover { background-color: lightpink }"
                      "QPushButton:pressed { background-color: indianred }" )
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.loginbutton)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that using `setLayout` multiple times is pointless, and that [`setAlignment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#alignment-prop) is referred to the *contents* (the text) of the line edit, not its position.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for this case, but among them is to use a container that has the minimum size to show all the widgets and that is established through a QGridLayout:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("MidiScribe - Login Window")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 800)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """background-color: crimson;
                            border-color: maroon;
                            border: 2.5px outset rgb(128, 128, 128);
                            border-radius: 3px;"""
        )

        self.username = QLineEdit(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.username.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.username.setStyleSheet("""background-color: white;""")

        self.password = QLineEdit(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.password.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.password.setStyleSheet("""background-color: white""")

        self.loginbutton = QPushButton("Login")
        self.loginbutton.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.loginbutton.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton { background-color: lightcoral }"
            "QPushButton:Hover { background-color: lightpink }"
            "QPushButton:pressed { background-color: indianred }"
        )

        container = QWidget(objectName="container")
        container.setStyleSheet("QWidget#container{border: none}")
        container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(container)
        lay.addWidget(self.username, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.password, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.loginbutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        container.setFixedSize(container.sizeHint())

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(container, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: really nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Just do alignment for mainLayout:

```
mainLayout.addWidget(self.loginbutton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
mainLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Because the OP requires to have *all* widgets aligned to the center, and the code you're providing is not enough, since the button will only by aligned to the left of the centered widgets, since setting the alignment of layout items only centers the layout, not its contents, and the widgets will still also be equally distributed vertically.